# Confused by windows keyboard event lParam

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, windows-messages

Part of the code:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(
    _In_ HWND   hwnd,
    _In_ UINT   uMsg,
    _In_ WPARAM wParam,
    _In_ LPARAM lParam)
{ ...
    switch(uMsg)
    { ...
        case WM_SYSKEYDOWN:
        case WM_SYSKEYUP:
        case WM_KEYDOWN:
        case WM_KEYUP:
        {
            uint8_t VKCODE = wParam;
            bool WasDown = ((lParam & (1<<30)) != 0);
            bool IsDown = ((lParam & (1<<31)) == 0);
            if(WasDown != IsDown)
            {
                if(VKCode == 'W')
                {
                    OutputDebugStringA("W: ");
                    if(WasDown)
                    {
                        OutputDebugStringA("WasDown ");
                    }
                    if(IsDown)
                    {
                        OutputDebugStringA("IsDown ");
                    }
                    OutputDebugStringA("\n");
                }
                else if(VKCode == 'A')
                {
                    OutputDebugStringA("A\n");
                }
                ...
            }
        } break;
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

**1)** First, when I press 'A', will always output 2 'A's.

**2)** Second, according to this page:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/inputdev/wm-keyup

> 30    The previous key state. The value is always 1 for a WM_KEYUP message.
>
> 31    The transition state. The value is always 1 for a WM_KEYUP message.

then (lParam & (1<<31)) will always be non-zero, so IsDown will always be false, but when I press(hit and release) 'W' it will output:

```
IsDown
WasDown
```

How come it will output "IsDown" if bool IsDown is always false?

**3)** If I comment out 3 cases before WM_KEYUP like this:

```
// case WM_SYSKEYDOWN:
// case WM_SYSKEYUP:
// case WM_KEYDOWN:
```

then when I press 'A' will only output one 'A', when I press 'W' will only output "WasDown", never "IsDown". I didn't wrote any code under previous 3 cases before comment them out anyway, what happened?

BTW, I'm following this video if anyone wants to see the full code:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J3y1x54vyIQ

Comment: From what you say under point 3 it sounds like you don't quite understand how `case` statements work in C/C++. The way you have your code structured, all four messages will be processed the same way. As far as #2 goes, bit 30 and 31 are always 1 for `WM_KEYUP` but for `WM_KEYDOWN` bit 30 can be 0 or 1 and bit 31 is always 0.

Comment: @JonathanPotter So when I press a key, WindowProc process the message for WM_KEYDOWN and WM_KEYUP with the same block of code under case KEY_UP?

Comment: Yes, because when you have multiple `case` statements without a `break` in between them, control will flow through them from the matching `case` to the next `break`.

Comment: https://cboard.cprogramming.com/cplusplus-programming/170137-jumping-into-cplusplus-chapter-7-activity-2-twelve-days-christmas.html

Comment: @JonathanPotter   Thank you, now I get it